# why is heroku telling me to update CLI when i just downloaded it?

Tags: git, heroku

I am trying to push my app to heroku to deploy it.  when I type the command "git push heroku master" I get the following message:

This is the legacy Heroku CLI. Please install the new CLI from https://cli.heroku.com

I already downloaded it 3 times so it is not an issue of it being outdated. and besides it is supposed to update automatically. please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, using Windows 10. Found this [issue](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/495) and uninstalled everything with Heroku in the name from "Settings --> Apps & features". I also deleted any remaining Heroku folder and PATH-variables. Then I installed Heroku CLI fresh from [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli).

Had some troubles getting it working again after I installed it. Seems like the installer set incorrect PATH. Ended up restarting my computer, that did the trick. Typed `heroku` into CMD, and it updated my CLI. Then I typed `heroku login` to log in and could use the CLI like before.